# Im evoking funtion too many times inside directive *ngFor, is there anything i can do better?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In directive `*ngFor` I iterate through map (tour_id -> number of reserved tours). As you can see, I am envoking function `getTour` multiple times.
Can I do better?

```html
 <tr *ngFor="let object of reservedTours | keyvalue" [ngClass] = "checkSumCondition() ? 'lower' : 'higher'">
    <td>{{getTour(object.key).name}}</td>
    <td>{{getTour(object.key).country}}</td>
    <td>{{getTour(object.key).price * object.value}} USD</td>
    <td>{{getTour(object.key).startDate}} </td>
    <td>{{getTour(object.key).endDate}}</td>
    <td>{{object.value}}</td>
```

Tour is object that has properties like id, price, ...

```js
  getTour(_id: string): Tour{
    return this.tours.find((tour: Tour) => tour._id === _id)
  }
```

Comment: 1) Don’t post code as image (we need to copy and paste it); and 2) Don’t post the code on third-party sites, post it right here

Comment: you can prepare array of you tours in your component and only then iterate in template without calculating value that will be displayed

Comment: can you show what is in `reservedTours` variable and `this.tours` as well? It would be better if you provide working example in Stackblitz so anyone can run it and suggest you answer

Comment: reservedTours is a Map<string, number> (string is representing id of tour, and number is representing number of reserved tours with particular id). this.tours is array of tour object

Comment: so filter this.tours based reservedTours: leave only those items with ids inside  reservedTours. Then do ngFor on this filtered array. In template you will have something like this: `<td>{{filteredItem.country}}</td>`